# Overfull warning for a minipage

Tags: minipage

What is wrong with this code (I get an overfull \hbox warning in the line 5)?

```
\documentclass[final]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\blindtext
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\blindtext
\end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\noindent` before starting `minipage`. Additionally, load package `showframe` to see what is gong on.